# Density of primes is $1/\log x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The prime number theorem states that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \pi(x)/Li(x) = 1$, if we denote $\pi(x) := \sum_{p \le x} 1$ for the prime counting function and $Li(x) = \int_2^x \frac{ dt}{\log t}$ for the logarithmic integral.

Since we are integrating the function $1/\log t$ to get $Li(x)$, we may informally interpret the above statement as prime numbers having density $1/\log x$ around each number $x > 0$. I'm curious of the sharpest rigorous formulation of this insight. One formulation of this would be to find the smallest function $a(x)$ so that:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(x) - \pi(x-a)}{Li(x) - Li(x-a)} = 1$$

If there is a more illuminating / alternative existing result that distills the above intuition, please let me know too!

---

Here is a proof that $a(x) = \sqrt x (\log x)^3$ satisfies the above criterion, if the Riemann hypothesis (RH) is true.

Under the RH, Schoenfeld showed that $|\pi(x) - Li(x)| < \sqrt{x} \log x$ (There is a sharper version that comes with the constant $\frac 1{8\pi}$ and $x>2700$ but I'll use this simpler version here, which I read to be true). Then for $a(x) = \sqrt x (\log x)^3$, we have:
\begin{align*}
& |(\pi(x)-\pi(x-a)) - (Li(x) - Li(x-a))| \\
=& |(\pi(x)-Li(x)) - (\pi(x-a) - Li(x-a))| \\
<& |\pi(x)-Li(x))| +  |\pi(x-a) - Li(x-a)| \\
<& 2 \sqrt x \log x
\end{align*}
(here $a = a(x)$) Then we note that:
$$\frac{2\sqrt x \log x }{Li(x) - Li(x-a)} < \frac{2\sqrt x \log x }{a / \log x} =  \frac{2 \sqrt x \log x}{\sqrt x (\log x)^2} = \frac{2}{\log x}$$
so that
\begin{align*}
& \frac{|(\pi(x)-\pi(x-a)) - (Li(x) - Li(x-a))|}{Li(x) - Li(x-a)} < \frac{2}{\log x} \\
\implies & \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(x)-\pi(x-a)}{Li(x) - Li(x-a)} = 1
\end{align*}

**Remark.** Even though $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt x (\log x)^3}{x} = 0$, in fact $\sqrt x (\log x)^3$ is larger than $x$ even for $x = 10^7$, although the inequality is reversed for $x = 10^8$. In view of this, we can instead say that $a(x) = x^{\frac12 + \epsilon}$ works for every $\epsilon>0$ too, and also we are free to use any $x$ in this case.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Under the RH $\pi(x)=\sum_{n\le x}1/\log n +O(\log n/n^{1/2})$.

Comment: I'm curious of how far one can push the analogy of "density" without having to integrate through the entire domain from $0$ to $x$. A true notion of density would average a function over a small interval, which is the reason that I suggested the formulation using small $a(x)$.

Comment: Under the RH any function such that $a(x)=o(x)$ and $x^{1/2}\log^2 x=o(a(x))$ works as $\pi(x+a(x))-\pi(x)=\sum_{n\in [x,x+a(x)]} 1/\log n+O(x^{1/2}\log x)$ $= a(x)/\log x + O(a(x)/\log^2 x)+ O(x^{1/2}\log x)$.

Comment: Indeed, I derived that too as written on the question. I was curious if the assertion can be sharpened, or whether such an assertion would hold true in the absence of RH.